# How to loop through Multiple Machines in a PSSession such that I execute Invoke-Command against the correct Machine?

Tags: powershell

My Powershell Script below wants to retrieve multiple registry values, from a set of Windows Services (200+), from multiple machines (up to 8 machines). Since I'm retrieving quite a lot of info, I decided to use `New-PSSession`.

But whenever it gets into the `scriptblock` of the `foreach` loop, it executes it on the incorrect machine and thus eventually errors out saying

**The Error:**

```
Cannot find path 'HKLM:\system\currentcontrolset\services\SomeServiceName' because it does not exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (HKLM:\system\cu...ces\SomeServiceName:String) [Get-ItemProperty], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand
    + PSComputerName        : WEB002
```

**The Powershell Script:**

```
$MyCustomServiceArray = @()
$c1 = 0
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName WEB001, WEB002 
$MyCustomServices = Invoke-Command -session $s -scriptblock {Get-WmiObject -Class win32_service |
                    Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Displayname -like "*Special Service for Me*"} |
                    Select PSComputerName, Name, DisplayName, State, StartMode, StartName, PathName |
                    Sort DisplayName}


foreach($MyCustomService in $MyCustomServices)
{
    $MyCustomServiceName = $MyCustomService.Name
    $RegistryPathForService = "hklm:\system\currentcontrolset\services\$MyCustomServiceName"
    $c1 += 1
    Write-Host "$c1. $MyCustomServiceName`n"
    
    $StartUpParameter = Invoke-Command -session $s -scriptblock {(Get-ItemProperty $using:RegistryPathForService).startupparameter}
    if ($StartUpParameter -eq $null) {$StartUpParameter = ""}
    
    $DatabaseServerName = Invoke-Command -session $s -scriptblock {(Get-ItemProperty $using:RegistryPathForService).servername}
    if ($DatabaseServerName -eq $null) {$DatabaseServerName = ""}
    
    $DatabaseName = Invoke-Command -session $s -scriptblock {(Get-ItemProperty $using:RegistryPathForService).database}
    if ($DatabaseName -eq $null) {$DatabaseName = ""}
    
    $NetType = Invoke-Command -session $s -scriptblock {(Get-ItemProperty $using:RegistryPathForService).nettype}
    if ($NetType -eq $null) {$NetType = ""}
    
    $ObjectCacheSize = Invoke-Command -session $s -scriptblock {(Get-ItemProperty $using:RegistryPathForService).objectcache}
    if ($ObjectCacheSize -eq $null) {$ObjectCacheSize = 0}
    
    $Row = "" | Select HostName,ServiceName,StartUpParameter,ServiceDisplayName,Status,StartUpType, `
                       DatabaseServerName,DatabaseName,NetType,ObjectCacheSize, `
                       LogOnName,PathName
    $Row.HostName           = $MyCustomService.PSComputerName
    $Row.ServiceName        = $MyCustomService.Name
    $Row.StartUpParameter   = $StartUpParameter
    $Row.ServiceDisplayName = $MyCustomService.DisplayName
    $Row.Status             = $MyCustomService.State
    $Row.StartUpType        = $MyCustomService.StartMode
    $Row.DatabaseServerName = $DatabaseServerName
    $Row.DatabaseName       = $DatabaseName
    $Row.NetType            = $NetType
    $Row.ObjectCacheSize    = $ObjectCacheSize  
    $Row.LogOnName          = $MyCustomService.StartName
    $Row.PathName           = $MyCustomService.PathName
    $MyCustomServiceArray += $Row
}
$MyCustomServiceArray | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "C:\Users\GaryTheBrave\Documents\AllMyCustomServices.csv"
```

Is there a way to loop through these Multiple Machines in the correct order?

Comment: from the help for `New-PSSession` >>> If you enter multiple computer names,  `New-PSSession` creates multiple PSSession objects, one for each computer. <<< ///// so, have you tried iterating thru the sessions to see which one goes to the desired target system?

Comment: You can do a `foreach ($computer in $Array) { New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer`

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: Thank you. That was it. Looping through sessions was the answer.

Comment: @GaryTheBrave - kool! glad to have helped ... and that you got it working as needed ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution was, as [Lee_Daily](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) hinted, **Looping through sessions**. Thanks [Lee_Daily](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey)!!!

Here is the modified Powershell Script that works perfectly

```
$MyCustomServiceArray = @()
$c1 = 0
$sessions = New-PSSession -ComputerName WEB001, WEB002 
foreach($session in $sessions)
{
    $MyCustomServices = Invoke-Command -session $session -scriptblock {Get-WmiObject -Class win32_service |
                        Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Displayname -like "*Special Service for Me*"} |
                        Select PSComputerName, Name, DisplayName, State, StartMode, StartName, PathName |
                        Sort DisplayName}

    foreach($MyCustomService in $MyCustomServices)
    {
        $MyCustomServiceName = $MyCustomService.Name
        $RegistryPathForService = "hklm:\system\currentcontrolset\services\$MyCustomServiceName"
        $c1 += 1
        Write-Host "$c1. $MyCustomServiceName`n"
    
        $StartUpParameter = Invoke-Command -session $session -scriptblock {(Get-ItemProperty $using:RegistryPathForService).startupparameter}
        if ($StartUpParameter -eq $null) {$StartUpParameter = ""}
    
        $DatabaseServerName = Invoke-Command -session $session -scriptblock {(Get-ItemProperty $using:RegistryPathForService).servername}
        if ($DatabaseServerName -eq $null) {$DatabaseServerName = ""}
    
        $DatabaseName = Invoke-Command -session $session -scriptblock {(Get-ItemProperty $using:RegistryPathForService).database}
        if ($DatabaseName -eq $null) {$DatabaseName = ""}
    
        $NetType = Invoke-Command -session $session -scriptblock {(Get-ItemProperty $using:RegistryPathForService).nettype}
        if ($NetType -eq $null) {$NetType = ""}
    
        $ObjectCacheSize = Invoke-Command -session $session -scriptblock {(Get-ItemProperty $using:RegistryPathForService).objectcache}
        if ($ObjectCacheSize -eq $null) {$ObjectCacheSize = 0}
    
        $Row = "" | Select HostName,ServiceName,StartUpParameter,ServiceDisplayName,Status,StartUpType, `
                           DatabaseServerName,DatabaseName,NetType,ObjectCacheSize, `
                           LogOnName,PathName
        $Row.HostName           = $MyCustomService.PSComputerName
        $Row.ServiceName        = $MyCustomService.Name
        $Row.StartUpParameter   = $StartUpParameter
        $Row.ServiceDisplayName = $MyCustomService.DisplayName
        $Row.Status             = $MyCustomService.State
        $Row.StartUpType        = $MyCustomService.StartMode
        $Row.DatabaseServerName = $DatabaseServerName
        $Row.DatabaseName       = $DatabaseName
        $Row.NetType            = $NetType
        $Row.ObjectCacheSize    = $ObjectCacheSize  
        $Row.LogOnName          = $MyCustomService.StartName
        $Row.PathName           = $MyCustomService.PathName
        $MyCustomServiceArray += $Row
    }
}
$MyCustomServiceArray | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "C:\Users\GaryTheBrave\Documents\AllMyCustomServices.csv"
```

Comment: neat! [*grin*] ///// if you have the time, you may want to look into the `[PSCustomObject]` type accelerator. it would make that `$Row` section of your code somewhat more direct - and simpler.